# In C++, can I use multithreading tools to synchronize UNIX signals with my main program?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, unix, signals

Does a signal handler set with `sigaction` run in its own thread? Can I use Pthreads tools to synchronize my signal handler with my main program, like Pthreads mutexes? Can I use C++11 tools like `mutex` and `atomic`?

Sorry if the question is a bit too general but I'm really confused about the relation between signals and threads.

I'm working on Linux but the question applies to UNIX in general.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952262/signal-handler-function-in-multithreaded-environment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The only functions you can safely call in signal handlers are async-signal-safe functions.  For Linux, you can find a list of such functions in the [signal.7 man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), under "Async-signal-safe functions", a bit more than halfway down the page.

Any function not listed as an async-signal-safe can not be safely called in a signal handler.

Note that the only synchronization function listed as async-signal-safe on Linux is `sem_post()`.