# sigaction : using "void (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);"

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, signals

In `sigaction` manpage it's written :

`sa_sigaction` also specifies the action to be associated with `signum`.
This function receives the signal number as its first argument, a
pointer to a `siginfo_t` as its second argument and a pointer to a ucon-
text_t (cast to `void*`) as its third argument.

So we can pass arguments to the signal handler (throught `void*`), but I
can't find the way.
Is there no way to put it anywhere?

Example :

```
struct ping_val
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
};

void ping(int sig, siginfo_t *siginf, void *ptr) 
{
    // ....
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa_ping;
    ping_val foo;
    foo.data1 = 3;
    foo.data2 = 4;
    sa_ping.sa_sigaction = ping;
    sigemptyset(&sa_ping.sa_mask);
    sa_ping.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa_ping, NULL);
    // ....
}
```

Where I can pass `foo` structure value in argument in ping (with a cast in `struct *`)???

Comment: No you can't pass arbitrary data to the signal handler. You only have control of the `sigaction` structure and it have no user-data field. Also, for the three-argument variant of the signal function to be called you *must* specify the `SA_SIGINFO` flag.

Comment: Your confusion probably comes from the `u` in the name `ucontext_t`? It doesn't stand for "user data", it's a structure for the stack frame of the thread causing the signal.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass any arguments to a signal handler because you never call it yourselves. A signal handler is called by the OS that doesn't know anything about your arguments.

The standard way to have a signal handler communicate with the main program is through global (or file-scoped) variables.

Answer (score 0):

The [`siginfo_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) structure that a signal handler receives contains a `union sigval si_value` member:

```
union sigval {
    int    sival_int; // Integer signal value 
    void  *sival_ptr; // Pointer signal value 
}
```

So if you're sending signals within a single process (or among forks, in some cases, I suppose), you can send a pointer to some data.

I know of two ways to send a `sigval` value to a signal handler:

If you use [`timer_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html) to create a timer, you pass it a `sigevent` struct, which contains a `union sigval sigev_value` member. By convention, user code will set `sigev_value.sival_ptr` to be the timer ID, so that the signal handler can distinguish among several timers if necessary, but you can set it to any `void *` value.

If you use [sigqueue](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigqueue.html) (as opposed to `kill`, `raise`, faults, etc.) to send the signals, you give it a `union sigval` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> *So we can pass arguments to the signal handler [through the void* ucontext_t argument], but I can't find the way.*

There is no such way to be found — the `ucontext_t` argument is set by the system itself and refers to *["the receiving thread's context that was interrupted when the signal was delivered."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html#tag_16_540_03)*

(Specifically, [by spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_42_03) it contains at least a reference to that interrupted context, and to a machine-specific representation of that context, and also the current context's stack and its set of blocked signals.)

You probably don't need any of this.  If you want your program to take some action and/or modify its state on receipt of a signal, you've a limited number of tactics that can be safely used in a signal handler ([`volatile sigatomic_t` flags, self-pipes,
 platform-specific interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12952362/132382)), but then your main loop can of course do whatever you want with the knowledge that SIGFOO was just received.