# How to call sigaction from C++

Tags: c++, signals, sigaction

I know how to use it in C (with signal.h), but the `<csignal>` library is provided in C++ and I want to know if it includes sigaction? I tried running it but it said not found. I was wondering if I did something wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <csignal>

namespace {
  volatile bool quitok = false;
  void handle_break(int a) {
    if (a == SIGINT) quitok = true;
  }
  std::sigaction sigbreak;
  sigbreak.sa_handler = &handle_break;
  sigbreak.sa_mask = 0;
  sigbreak.sa_flags = 0;
  if (std::sigaction(SIGINT, &sigbreak, NULL) != 0) std::perror("sigaction");
}

int main () {
  std::string line = "";
  while (!::quitok) {
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work.
EDIT:
By "doesn't work", I mean the compiler fails and says there's no std::sigaction function or struct.

sigaction is C POSIX isn't it?

Comment: sigaction is not part of Standard C++, so wheter you can use it is down to your implementation

Comment: Unrelated: `volatile bool` may not be good enough. More on that: [set flag in signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907477/set-flag-in-signal-handler)

Comment: Describe "But for some reason it doesn't work." in more detail. Does it not compile? Does the signal not get handled? Does the program crash? ...

Comment: "but it said not found" *What* wasn't found? *What* said it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sigaction` is in POSIX, not the C++ standard, and it's in the global namespace.
You'll also need the `struct` keyword to differentiate between `sigaction`, the struct,
and `sigaction`, the function.
Finally, the initialization code will need to be in a function -- you can't have it 
in file scope.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <signal.h>

namespace {
  volatile sig_atomic_t quitok = false;
  void handle_break(int a) {
    if (a == SIGINT) quitok = true;
  }
}

int main () {
  struct sigaction sigbreak;
  sigbreak.sa_handler = &handle_break;
  sigemptyset(&sigbreak.sa_mask);
  sigbreak.sa_flags = 0;
  if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sigbreak, NULL) != 0) std::perror("sigaction");
  //...
}
```

Comment: Should I use the implementation in `<signal.h>` or namespaced one in `<csignal>`?

Comment: @AidenWoodruff `signal.h` is guaranteed to have it on a POSIX plaftorm. I don't think that's true for `<csignal>`.

Comment: why quitok is declared in an unnamed namespace?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani AFAIK, it should have the same effect as declaring each of the such-enclosed declarations as `static`.