# SIGTERM is followed by SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, linux, signals, epoll

I have a program that uses `epoll` to wait for certain events (like data available in a socket, etc). This program is running as a service started by `systemd`. What I want to achieve is a proper shutdown. So I have installed a signal handler that will catch the `SIGTERM`. From my understanding, `systemd` will first send a `SIGTERM` followed by a `SIGKILL` after a delay, so the process has the chance for a proper shutdown.

My signal handler looks like this:

```
struct sigaction act;
::memset(&act, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
act.sa_handler = sigterm;
if (sigaction(signal, &act, NULL) == -1)
{
    logger_.explode("Error setting up signal %d (%d)", signal, errno);
}
```

With my function of `sigterm` beeing:

```
void sigterm(int signo)
{
    logger_->info("SIGTERM received. Quitting.");
    shutdown_if_->init_shutdown();
}
```

Whereas `shutdown_if_` will trigger a fd to be written to that is hanged into the poll as as quit event (created with `pipe`).

What I expect to happen: The process will continue as I have catched the `SIGTERM` and will begin to terminate. Instead of that, after the signal is catched, I will receive a `SIGSEGV` as something seems to be messed up. When I look at it with a debugger the whole stack seems to be hella messed up (local variables missing, etc).

When I use the shutdown function of the poll in another context that with signals, everything works fine, static code analysis does not find anything as well. I am really stuck here.

Please tell me if you want any more informations, I do not really know how to put this problem.

Comment: Is your signal handler doing anything that isn't allowed according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal)? (See the *The behavior is undefined if any signal handler performs any of the following* section)

Comment: As POSIX, you might be interested in [here](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) as well. Following @Kevin's comment: `logger_->info` might be critical. I'd assume file IO being involved, seldom a good idea to do in a signal handler...

Comment: In my experience, signal handlers aren't allowed to do pretty much all the things you want to do in them.

Comment: Thank you very much, the information is very useful. I am investigating now which calls are not that good in my handler. thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks a lot. There were some issues here. What I have done now is to use the fact that epoll gets interrupted with error EINTR when a signal triggers. That way I can just set a bool in the handler and check on EINTR and this bool. If only EINTR is given, restart the poll, if EINTR and the bool are set -> quit poll. Everything works fine now!

Comment: make sure you use correct flag, typically you can't just use bool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907477/set-flag-in-signal-handler . Also make sure you take care of reentrancy and multi-threading issues with signals (if this is MT process -- signal gets delivered to random thread).