# C Gps nmea parser from linux serial port does not parse the last line of the read buffer

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, nmea

I need to create a c gps nmea parser for a board I'm working on (Cubietruck with armbian debian jessie 8.0) . Based on several examples I found on the internet I concluded in the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int fd = -1;
int end_of_loop= 0;

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
  if(sig == SIGINT)
  {
    printf("GPS parsing stopped by SIGINT\n");
    end_of_loop = 1;
    close(fd);
  }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct termios newt;
  char *nmea_line;
  char *parser;
  double latitude;
  float longitude;
  float altitude;

  signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

  fd = open("/dev/ttyACM2", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
  if (fd >= 0)
  {
    tcgetattr(fd, &newt);
    newt.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         
    newt.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); 
    newt.c_oflag = 0;               

    newt.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);               
    newt.c_cflag |= CS8;                       
    newt.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);         
    newt.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;                   

    newt.c_lflag = 0;                            

    newt.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0; 
    newt.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; 
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &newt);



  usleep(100000);

  while(end_of_loop == 0)
  {

    char read_buffer[1000];
    read(fd, &read_buffer,1000);
    //printf("|%s|", r_buf);

    nmea_line = strtok(read_buffer, "\n");

    while (nmea_line != NULL)
    {

      parser = strstr(nmea_line, "$GPRMC");
      if (parser != NULL)
      {
        printf("|%s| \n", nmea_line);
        char *token = strtok(nmea_line, ",");
        int index = 0;
        while (token != NULL)
        {
          if (index == 3)
          {
            latitude = atof(token);
            printf("found latitude: %s %f\n", token, latitude);
          }
          if (index == 5)
          {
            longitude = atof(token);
            printf("found longitude: %s %f\n", token, longitude);
          }
          token = strtok(NULL, ",");
          index++;
        }
      }

      parser = strstr(nmea_line, "$GPGGA");
      if (parser != NULL)
      {
        printf("|%s| \n", nmea_line);
        char *token = strtok(nmea_line, ",");
        int index = 0;
        while (token != NULL)
        {
          if (index == 13)
          {
            altitude = atof(token);
            printf("found altitude: %s %f\n", token, altitude);
          }
          token = strtok(NULL, ",");
          index++;
        }

      }



      printf("|%s| \n", nmea_line);
      nmea_line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    usleep(500000);

  }

  close(fd);

  return 0;

  }
  else
  {
    printf("Port cannot be opened");
    return -1;
  }
}
```

For the time being I test negative case where there is no GPS fix. 
The output from the serial port  for that case is for every read :

```
$GNGNS,,,,,,NNN,,,,,,*1D
$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
```

When I run the code I get parse print outs for the GPGGA but not for the GPRMC:

```
GNGNS,,,,,,NNN,,,,,,*1D
| GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
| GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
| GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00
| GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
|$GPGGA|
| GNGNS,,,,,,NNN,,,,,,*1D
| GNGNS,,,,,,NNN,,,,,,*1D
| GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
| GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
| GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00
| GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
|$GPGGA|
```

I assume that has something to do with the fact that GPRMC is on the last line and when `nmea_line = strtok(NULL, "\n");` is executed then the nmea_lime becomes NULL. I added a dummy line on the read_buffer with `strcat` but with no success.
I printed the index and I found that for GPGGA only index = 3 is achieved. I increased the usleep time but there was no change. 
Has anyone any idea what I can do to achieve correct parsing?

Comment: Dont use strtok(). It fails to recognise consecutive delimiters.

Comment: @wildplasser What can I use instead ?

Comment: You could use strchr(),  or compare characters manually. Best would be to construct  a small DFA.(your code already is very close to a DFA)

Comment: Also: `read(fd, &read_buffer,1000);` does not respect line-breaks(and the buffer will not be NUL-terminated!) . You'll have to find `'\n'` characters, too, to sync to the end-of-line/beginning-of-next-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of parsing seems OK, but the implementation has a few problems though.

I wrote many years ago a gps nmea parser, and as far as I can remember, the
lines ended with `"\r\n"`, that would seem also the case because for this line

```
printf("|%s| \n", nmea_line);
```

you get

```
| GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
```

If you change it to

```
printf(">%s| \n", nmea_line);
```

you'll most probably see

```
< GNGNS,,,,,,NNN,,,,,,*1D
```

A second problem is that you are using `strtok` in a reentrant kind of way. At
the beginning of the loop, you do `nmea_line = strtok(read_buffer, "\n");`. Then
you go to parse the line and enter a new loop. Then you do stuff line 
`char *token = strtok(nmea_line, ",");` and by doing this `strtok` forgets the
information about the first call.

At the end of everything you do again `nmea_line = strtok(NULL, "\n");`, but
this `NULL` applies to which `strtok`? Depending on the output you will never
know but it won't certainly match to with to `nmea_line = strtok(read_buffer, "\n");`.

Luckly there is a reentrant version of `strtok`: `strtok_r`

> *man strtok*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
>
> char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strtok()` function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or more nonempty tokens. On the first call to `strtok()`, the string to be
>   parsed should be specified in `str`. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, `str` must be `NULL`.
>
> [...]
>
> The `strtok_r()` function is a reentrant version `strtok()`.  The saveptr argument is a pointer to a `char*`
>   variable that is used internally by `strtok_r()` **in order to maintain context between successive calls**
>   that parse the same string.

Example:

```
char line[] = "a:b:c,d:e:f,x:y:z";

char *s1, *s2, *token1, *token2, *in1, *in2;

in1 = line;

while(token1 = strtok_r(in1, ",", &s1))
{
    in1 = NULL; // for subsequent calls

    in2 = token1;

    printf("First block: %s\n", token1);

    while(token2 = strtok_r(in2, ":", &s2))
    {
        in2 = NULL; // for subsequent calls

        printf("  val: %s\n", token2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First block: a:b:c
  val: a
  val: b
  val: c
First block: d:e:f
  val: d
  val: e
  val: f
First block: x:y:z
  val: x
  val: y
  val: z
```

Another problem that I see is this:

```
while(...)
{
    read(fd, &read_buffer,1000);

    nmea_line = strtok(read_buffer, "\n");
}
```

The `read` function, unlike `fgets`, does not read strings, it reads bytes. That
means that `read` doesn't care what it's reading. If the sequence happens to be
a sequence of values that match the values of the ASCII table, it won't add the
`'\0'`-terminating byte in your read buffer. And that's a problem, because you
are using functions that expect valid strings. If the read input does not
contain a newline, `strtok` will continue reading until it finds `'\0'` and if
that byte is not present, it will read beyond the limits. This is undefined
behaviour.

The second problem with doing this is that once again `read` doesn't care about
the bytes you are ready, you are not reading lines, you are ready a 1000 byte
block of memory which may or might not contain strings. It is most likely that
the block does not contain strings, because `/dev/ttyACM2` will generate an
endless stream and never send `'\0'` to the user.

I would use `fgets` to get a line and parse it, after that get another line, and
so on. Because you've only got the file descriptor, you should use:

> *[fdopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fdopen.html)*
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);
> ```
>
> The `fdopen()` function associates a stream with the existing file descriptor, `fd`.
>   The `mode` of the stream (one of the values `"r"`, `"r+"`, `"w"`, `"w+"`, `"a"`, `"a+"`)
>   must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor.
>   The file position indicator of the new stream is set to that belonging to `fd`,
>   and the error and end-of-file indicators are cleared.  Modes `"w"` or `"w+"` do not cause
>   truncation  of  the  file. The  file  descriptor is not dup'ed, and will be closed when the
>   stream created by `fdopen()` is closed. The result of applying `fdopen()`
>   to a shared memory object is undefined.

So I would do:

```
FILE *f = fopen(fd, "r");


// the gps nmea lines are never that long
char line[64];

char *t1_save;

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, f))
{
    // get rid of \r\n
    line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;

    parser = strstr(line, "$GPRMC");
    if(parser)
    {
        // do the parsing
    }

    ...
}
```

In this version you wouldn't even need `strtok_r` because you wouldn't need to
nest `strtok` calls.

---

**edit**

There is one thing that I've missed earlier:

```
int end_of_loop= 0;

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
  if(sig == SIGINT)
  {
    printf("GPS parsing stopped by SIGINT\n");
    end_of_loop = 1;
    close(fd);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    while(end_of_loop == 0)
    {
    }
}
```

Depending in the optimazations of your compiler, you will end up in an endless
loop, even after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The compiler might
optimize the `while` loop to `while(1)`, because in `main` the `end_of_loop`
variable is never altered, so there is no point to always check for that value.

When trying to stop loops with catching signals, it's best to at least declare
the variable as `volatile`, so that the compiler does not optimize that variable
away. Mostly (see [1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488791/proper-usage-of-volatile-sig-atomic-t)) the best way to do this is:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t end_of_loop= 0;

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
  if(sig == SIGINT)
  {
    printf("GPS parsing stopped by SIGINT\n");
    end_of_loop = 1;
    close(fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;` will do it in one sweep.

Comment: @Pablo Thanks a million for you through answer. I'  m quite new in linux serial port programming. One question when you mention "In this version you wouldn't even need strtok_r" you mean than I can use my code as it is , or should I do something else?

Comment: @dk13 you can't use your code without fixing it. The point of my answer was to tell you which parts are wrong and how you would fix it. Using `fgets` you don't need to use `strtok` to find the newline, so you don't have to nest the `strtok` calls. Please read the answer more careful, you'll get it.

Comment: @wildplasser yes I know. Sadly I've had devices in the past that in midstream they only send newline and not the `\r`, thus messing with the parser. Sometimes a device of model "0.1" will return `\r\n` but when the customer buys years later model "0.5", the customer calls me and says "program doesn't work". After close inspection the manufacturer changed the protocol and sends now only newlines. That's why I do them separately, for all these kind of issues.

Comment: Cargo cult alert: `line[strcspn(line, "\n\r")] = 0;` would also work.

Comment: @wildplasser cargo cult alert? What does that mean? Provided that the order is always \r and \n, then yes, that would help. But I've seen all kinds of endings that are not present in the documentation of the manufacturer.

Comment: For `str[c]spn()` there is no order for the *set* of characters in the second argument; the first (non)match will end the scan. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: @wildplasser well, you're right, I updated my post, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to offend you. But knowing the `line[strcspn(line,...)] =0;` *trick*, and not knowing the strcspn() semantics seemed a bit strange to me...

Comment: @wildplasser hu? You didn't offend me, I acknowledge that your explanation was better than what I previously wrote. I **know** the semantics of `strcspn`, but I wanted to get rid of **both** of them if they appear in the line. But thinking about that made me realize that that is not necessary, so I updated my post.

Comment: @dk13 I've made an update of my answer, I've found something that I missed the first time.

Comment: @Pablo thanks for eveything you really saved my day. I'm almost finished. Regarding the gps nmea in normal cases the longest string is 
$GPRMC,125114.0,A,5232.061658,N,01316.491385,E,0.0,275.2,260118,0.0,E,A*04 which is about 75 characters, so in your opinion a 128 buffer  is ok ?

Comment: @dk13 yes, that would be ok, my 64 was just an estimate out of my memory, I don't have such a device at home so I wasn't able to check it.

Comment: @Pablo Thanks a lot for your support. The code did the job. I just observed that sometimes it didn't catch any input at all. In your opinion should I put usleep after the fdopen command or somewhere else or it's irrelevant meaning that there will be missed cases?

Comment: @dk13 I remember having a similar issue, so I put usleeps (100 ms) between the `open` and `fgets` and in the loop.